# Dialogflow CX Webhook requests parameter not saving?

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-cx

The webhook parameter value set is not saving or rather seems to not extract. The response body is shown as below.

```
{
    "is_authenticated": true
}
```

I have tried to manipulate the field path which I don't really have much options to begin with, still getting null.

`$.is_authenticated` < null
`$` < also null